# Table HEADERS fixed, but the borders move on chrome and don't appear on firefox

Tags: html, css

I need to fix the borders on my header table, on chrome, the top border disappears when I scroll down, and on firefox, it simply does not appears.

You can see it here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zyEwZq#anon-login

And open on both browsers to check it out.

I've tried to use others position, like fixed, but it didn't work.

```
<div id="dados-ordem-tabela" class="alphaBorda1 settingsConf shadow-box ativa-display-dialog">
<div class="titulo alphaBackground3">
    <a>Dados de Ordem</a>
</div>
<div class="menuSt">
    <ul class="settingsConf-ul">
        <li id="aba-dados-ordem" tab=".dados-ordem" class="mouseoverAlpha5 settingsConf-li tippy-cursor-point pri aq">Ordens</li>
        <li id="aba-dados-ordem-oms" tab=".dados-ordem-oms" class="mouseoverAlpha5 settingsConf-li tippy-cursor-point pri">Stop</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="dados-ordem style-tabela style-tabela-ordens menuBck" style="">
    <table>
        <thead class="cor-fundo-principal">
            <tr>
                <th class="cor-fundo-principal alphaborda1" valuetocsv="CANCELAR">CANCELAR</th>
                <th class="cor-fundo-principal alphaborda1" valuetocsv="C/V">C/V</th>
                <th class="cor-fundo-principal alphaborda1" valuetocsv="PAPEL">PAPEL</th>
                <th class="cor-fundo-principal alphaborda1" valuetocsv="QTD.">QTD.</th>
                <th class="cor-fundo-principal alphaborda1" valuetocsv="PREÇO">PREÇO</th>
                <th class="cor-fundo-principal alphaborda1" valuetocsv="STATUS">STATUS <span class="mouseoverAlpha5 icon-imgIntervalo"></span></th>
                <th class="cor-fundo-principal alphaborda1" valuetocsv="QTD. EX.">QTD. EX.</th>
                <th class="cor-fundo-principal alphaborda1" valuetocsv="PRÇ. MED.">PRÇ. MED.</th>
                <th class="cor-fundo-principal alphaborda1" valuetocsv="ORIGEM">ORIGEM</th>
                <th class="cor-fundo-principal alphaborda1" valuetocsv="DATA DE ENVIO">DATA DE ENVIO</th>
                <th class="cor-fundo-principal alphaborda1" valuetocsv="TIPO">TIPO</th>
                <th class="cor-fundo-principal alphaborda1" valuetocsv="VALIDADE">VALIDADE</th>
                <th class="cor-fundo-principal alphaborda1" valuetocsv="CÓD. CLI.">CÓD. CLI.</th>
                <th class="cor-fundo-principal alphaborda1" valuetocsv="ULT. ALT.">ULT. ALT.</th>
                <th class="cor-fundo-principal alphaborda1" valuetocsv="QTD. APARENTE">QTD. APARENTE</th>
                <th class="cor-fundo-principal alphaborda1" valuetocsv="SALDO">SALDO</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="alphaBackground3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 240, 120, 0.05);">
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='mouseoverAlpha5 icon-imgRemove cancela-ordem' value='4073684' ></span>"
                    class="text-center"><span class="mouseoverAlpha5 icon-imgRemove cancela-ordem" value="4073684"></span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="C" class="text-center CV">C</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WING19" class="text-center">WING19</td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="text-right">1</td>
                <td valuetocsv="87.055,00" class="text-right">87.055,00</td>
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='aberto'>Aberto</span>" class="text-left"><span class="aberto">Aberto</span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WEB" class="text-center">WEB</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018 11:30:28" class="">28/12/2018 11:30:28</td>
                <td valuetocsv="DIA" class="text-center">DIA</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018" class="">28/12/2018</td>
                <td valuetocsv="7332" class="">7332</td>
                <td valuetocsv="11:30:28:117" class="">11:30:28:117</td>
                <td valuetocsv="-" class=""> - </td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alphaBackground5" style="background-color: rgba(0, 240, 120, 0.05);">
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='mouseoverAlpha5 icon-imgRemove cancela-ordem' value='4073683' ></span>"
                    class="text-center"><span class="mouseoverAlpha5 icon-imgRemove cancela-ordem" value="4073683"></span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="C" class="text-center CV">C</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WING19" class="text-center">WING19</td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="text-right">1</td>
                <td valuetocsv="87.080,00" class="text-right">87.080,00</td>
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='aberto'>Aberto</span>" class="text-left"><span class="aberto">Aberto</span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WEB" class="text-center">WEB</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018 11:30:27" class="">28/12/2018 11:30:27</td>
                <td valuetocsv="DIA" class="text-center">DIA</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018" class="">28/12/2018</td>
                <td valuetocsv="7332" class="">7332</td>
                <td valuetocsv="11:30:27:970" class="">11:30:27:970</td>
                <td valuetocsv="-" class=""> - </td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alphaBackground3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 240, 120, 0.05);">
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='mouseoverAlpha5 icon-imgRemove cancela-ordem' value='4073682' ></span>"
                    class="text-center"><span class="mouseoverAlpha5 icon-imgRemove cancela-ordem" value="4073682"></span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="C" class="text-center CV">C</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WING19" class="text-center">WING19</td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="text-right">1</td>
                <td valuetocsv="87.135,00" class="text-right">87.135,00</td>
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='aberto'>Aberto</span>" class="text-left"><span class="aberto">Aberto</span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WEB" class="text-center">WEB</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018 11:30:27" class="">28/12/2018 11:30:27</td>
                <td valuetocsv="DIA" class="text-center">DIA</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018" class="">28/12/2018</td>
                <td valuetocsv="7332" class="">7332</td>
                <td valuetocsv="11:30:27:830" class="">11:30:27:830</td>
                <td valuetocsv="-" class=""> - </td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alphaBackground5" style="background-color: rgba(0, 240, 120, 0.05);">
                <td valuetocsv="-" class="text-center"> - </td>
                <td valuetocsv="C" class="text-center CV">C</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WING19" class="text-center">WING19</td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="text-right">1</td>
                <td valuetocsv="87.205,00" class="text-right">87.205,00</td>
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='executada'>Executada</span>" class="text-left"><span class="executada">Executada</span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="">1</td>
                <td valuetocsv="87.205,0000" class="">87.205,0000</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WEB" class="text-center">WEB</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018 11:30:27" class="">28/12/2018 11:30:27</td>
                <td valuetocsv="DIA" class="text-center">DIA</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018" class="">28/12/2018</td>
                <td valuetocsv="7332" class="">7332</td>
                <td valuetocsv="11:36:34:917" class="">11:36:34:917</td>
                <td valuetocsv="-" class=""> - </td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alphaBackground3" style="background-color: rgba(252, 83, 83, 0.05);">
                <td valuetocsv="-" class="text-center"> - </td>
                <td valuetocsv="V" class="text-center CV">V</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WING19" class="text-center">WING19</td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="text-right">1</td>
                <td valuetocsv="87.290,00" class="text-right">87.290,00</td>
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='executada'>Executada</span>" class="text-left"><span class="executada">Executada</span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="">1</td>
                <td valuetocsv="87.305,0000" class="">87.305,0000</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WEB" class="text-center">WEB</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018 11:30:27" class="">28/12/2018 11:30:27</td>
                <td valuetocsv="DIA" class="text-center">DIA</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018" class="">28/12/2018</td>
                <td valuetocsv="7332" class="">7332</td>
                <td valuetocsv="11:30:28:300" class="">11:30:28:300</td>
                <td valuetocsv="-" class=""> - </td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alphaBackground5" style="background-color: rgba(252, 83, 83, 0.05);">
                <td valuetocsv="-" class="text-center"> - </td>
                <td valuetocsv="V" class="text-center CV">V</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WING19" class="text-center">WING19</td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="text-right">1</td>
                <td valuetocsv="87.335,00" class="text-right">87.335,00</td>
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='executada'>Executada</span>" class="text-left"><span class="executada">Executada</span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="">1</td>
                <td valuetocsv="87.335,0000" class="">87.335,0000</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WEB" class="text-center">WEB</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018 11:30:27" class="">28/12/2018 11:30:27</td>
                <td valuetocsv="DIA" class="text-center">DIA</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018" class="">28/12/2018</td>
                <td valuetocsv="7332" class="">7332</td>
                <td valuetocsv="11:30:49:663" class="">11:30:49:663</td>
                <td valuetocsv="-" class=""> - </td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alphaBackground3" style="background-color: rgba(252, 83, 83, 0.05);">
                <td valuetocsv="-" class="text-center"> - </td>
                <td valuetocsv="V" class="text-center CV">V</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WING19" class="text-center">WING19</td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="text-right">1</td>
                <td valuetocsv="87.320,00" class="text-right">87.320,00</td>
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='executada'>Executada</span>" class="text-left"><span class="executada">Executada</span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="">1</td>
                <td valuetocsv="87.320,0000" class="">87.320,0000</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WEB" class="text-center">WEB</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018 11:30:27" class="">28/12/2018 11:30:27</td>
                <td valuetocsv="DIA" class="text-center">DIA</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018" class="">28/12/2018</td>
                <td valuetocsv="7332" class="">7332</td>
                <td valuetocsv="11:30:34:423" class="">11:30:34:423</td>
                <td valuetocsv="-" class=""> - </td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alphaBackground5" style="background-color: rgba(252, 83, 83, 0.05);">
                <td valuetocsv="-" class="text-center"> - </td>
                <td valuetocsv="V" class="text-center CV">V</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WING19" class="text-center">WING19</td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="text-right">1</td>
                <td valuetocsv="87.290,00" class="text-right">87.290,00</td>
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='executada'>Executada</span>" class="text-left"><span class="executada">Executada</span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="">1</td>
                <td valuetocsv="87.305,0000" class="">87.305,0000</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WEB" class="text-center">WEB</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018 11:30:27" class="">28/12/2018 11:30:27</td>
                <td valuetocsv="DIA" class="text-center">DIA</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018" class="">28/12/2018</td>
                <td valuetocsv="7332" class="">7332</td>
                <td valuetocsv="11:30:28:300" class="">11:30:28:300</td>
                <td valuetocsv="-" class=""> - </td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alphaBackground3" style="background-color: rgba(252, 83, 83, 0.05);">
                <td valuetocsv="-" class="text-center"> - </td>
                <td valuetocsv="V" class="text-center CV">V</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WING19" class="text-center">WING19</td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="text-right">1</td>
                <td valuetocsv="87.240,00" class="text-right">87.240,00</td>
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='executada'>Executada</span>" class="text-left"><span class="executada">Executada</span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="">1</td>
                <td valuetocsv="87.255,0000" class="">87.255,0000</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WEB" class="text-center">WEB</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018 11:30:26" class="">28/12/2018 11:30:26</td>
                <td valuetocsv="DIA" class="text-center">DIA</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018" class="">28/12/2018</td>
                <td valuetocsv="7332" class="">7332</td>
                <td valuetocsv="11:35:35:683" class="">11:35:35:683</td>
                <td valuetocsv="-" class=""> - </td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alphaBackground5" style="background-color: rgba(252, 83, 83, 0.05);">
                <td valuetocsv="-" class="text-center"> - </td>
                <td valuetocsv="V" class="text-center CV">V</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WING19" class="text-center">WING19</td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="text-right">1</td>
                <td valuetocsv="87.185,00" class="text-right">87.185,00</td>
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='executada'>Executada</span>" class="text-left"><span class="executada">Executada</span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="">1</td>
                <td valuetocsv="87.205,0000" class="">87.205,0000</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WEB" class="text-center">WEB</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018 11:30:26" class="">28/12/2018 11:30:26</td>
                <td valuetocsv="DIA" class="text-center">DIA</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018" class="">28/12/2018</td>
                <td valuetocsv="7332" class="">7332</td>
                <td valuetocsv="11:41:48:920" class="">11:41:48:920</td>
                <td valuetocsv="-" class=""> - </td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alphaBackground3" style="background-color: rgba(252, 83, 83, 0.05);">
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='mouseoverAlpha5 icon-imgRemove cancela-ordem' value='4073674' ></span>"
                    class="text-center"><span class="mouseoverAlpha5 icon-imgRemove cancela-ordem" value="4073674"></span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="V" class="text-center CV">V</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WING19" class="text-center">WING19</td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="text-right">1</td>
                <td valuetocsv="87.140,00" class="text-right">87.140,00</td>
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='aberto'>Aberto</span>" class="text-left"><span class="aberto">Aberto</span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WEB" class="text-center">WEB</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018 11:30:26" class="">28/12/2018 11:30:26</td>
                <td valuetocsv="STP" class="text-center">STP</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018" class="">28/12/2018</td>
                <td valuetocsv="7332" class="">7332</td>
                <td valuetocsv="11:30:26:583" class="">11:30:26:583</td>
                <td valuetocsv="-" class=""> - </td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alphaBackground5" style="background-color: rgba(252, 83, 83, 0.05);">
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='mouseoverAlpha5 icon-imgRemove cancela-ordem' value='4073673' ></span>"
                    class="text-center"><span class="mouseoverAlpha5 icon-imgRemove cancela-ordem" value="4073673"></span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="V" class="text-center CV">V</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WING19" class="text-center">WING19</td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="text-right">1</td>
                <td valuetocsv="87.110,00" class="text-right">87.110,00</td>
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='aberto'>Aberto</span>" class="text-left"><span class="aberto">Aberto</span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WEB" class="text-center">WEB</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018 11:30:26" class="">28/12/2018 11:30:26</td>
                <td valuetocsv="STP" class="text-center">STP</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018" class="">28/12/2018</td>
                <td valuetocsv="7332" class="">7332</td>
                <td valuetocsv="11:30:26:517" class="">11:30:26:517</td>
                <td valuetocsv="-" class=""> - </td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alphaBackground3" style="background-color: rgba(252, 83, 83, 0.05);">
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='mouseoverAlpha5 icon-imgRemove cancela-ordem' value='4073672' ></span>"
                    class="text-center"><span class="mouseoverAlpha5 icon-imgRemove cancela-ordem" value="4073672"></span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="V" class="text-center CV">V</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WING19" class="text-center">WING19</td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="text-right">1</td>
                <td valuetocsv="87.055,00" class="text-right">87.055,00</td>
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='aberto'>Aberto</span>" class="text-left"><span class="aberto">Aberto</span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WEB" class="text-center">WEB</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018 11:30:26" class="">28/12/2018 11:30:26</td>
                <td valuetocsv="STP" class="text-center">STP</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018" class="">28/12/2018</td>
                <td valuetocsv="7332" class="">7332</td>
                <td valuetocsv="11:30:26:300" class="">11:30:26:300</td>
                <td valuetocsv="-" class=""> - </td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alphaBackground5" style="background-color: rgba(0, 240, 120, 0.05);">
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='mouseoverAlpha5 icon-imgRemove cancela-ordem' value='4073671' ></span>"
                    class="text-center"><span class="mouseoverAlpha5 icon-imgRemove cancela-ordem" value="4073671"></span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="C" class="text-center CV">C</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WING19" class="text-center">WING19</td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="text-right">1</td>
                <td valuetocsv="86.950,00" class="text-right">86.950,00</td>
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='aberto'>Aberto</span>" class="text-left"><span class="aberto">Aberto</span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WEB" class="text-center">WEB</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018 11:30:26" class="">28/12/2018 11:30:26</td>
                <td valuetocsv="DIA" class="text-center">DIA</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018" class="">28/12/2018</td>
                <td valuetocsv="7332" class="">7332</td>
                <td valuetocsv="11:30:26:210" class="">11:30:26:210</td>
                <td valuetocsv="-" class=""> - </td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alphaBackground3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 240, 120, 0.05);">
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='mouseoverAlpha5 icon-imgRemove cancela-ordem' value='4073670' ></span>"
                    class="text-center"><span class="mouseoverAlpha5 icon-imgRemove cancela-ordem" value="4073670"></span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="C" class="text-center CV">C</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WING19" class="text-center">WING19</td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="text-right">1</td>
                <td valuetocsv="86.945,00" class="text-right">86.945,00</td>
                <td valuetocsv="<span class='aberto'>Aberto</span>" class="text-left"><span class="aberto">Aberto</span></td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
                <td valuetocsv="0" class="">0</td>
                <td valuetocsv="WEB" class="text-center">WEB</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018 11:30:26" class="">28/12/2018 11:30:26</td>
                <td valuetocsv="DIA" class="text-center">DIA</td>
                <td valuetocsv="28/12/2018" class="">28/12/2018</td>
                <td valuetocsv="7332" class="">7332</td>
                <td valuetocsv="11:30:26:010" class="">11:30:26:010</td>
                <td valuetocsv="-" class=""> - </td>
                <td valuetocsv="1" class="">1</td>
            </tr>





        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    <button class="alphaBackground3 alphaBorda1 button bt-atualizar" type="button">Atualizar</button>
    <button class="alphaBackground3 alphaBorda1 button bt-cancelar" type="button">Fechar</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body .tippy-tooltip.menu-list-theme, .cor-fundo-principal, .sub-menu, .text-object, .include-indicator-manager, .ui-widget-content, .auth-content, .input-dialog, .settingsConf, .jQWCP-wWidget, .popover, .clockpicker-button, .txt-edit-quantidade-chart-trading, .dialog-long-click, .chart-txt, .tooltip-listas, .bts-compra-venda-mobile, .dialog-edit-stop-de-posicao {
background: #333333;
 }

.shadow-box {
box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #000;
}

.ativa-display-dialog {
display: block;
}

.settingsConf {
height: 75%;
float: left;
width: 80%;
top: 5%;
left: 10%;
position: absolute;
border-top: none;
border-radius: 0;
z-index: 99;
}

  :not(input):not(textarea) {
-webkit-user-select: none;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

a, span, div, input[type="button"], button, label, .clockpicker-tick, .btn-default, .input-lista-dinamica-layouts, .boleta-ajuste-input {
color: #fff;
}

 .settingsConf .titulo {
border-radius: 0;
width: 100%;
padding: 8px 0;
}

.alphaBackground3, table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2n) {
background: rgba(77, 77, 77, 1);
}

.titulo a {
margin-left: 5px;
}

.menuSt {
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
overflow-x: auto;
}

.settingsConf-ul {
height: 43px;
white-space: nowrap;
}

ul, li {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
list-style: none;
}

.settingsConf .menuSt ul li.pri {
padding-right: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
}

.settingsConf .menuSt ul li.aq {
border-bottom: 3px solid #67CAD4;
}

.settingsConf-li {
font-size: 15px;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 10px 0 10px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}

.settingsConf .menuSt ul li.aq {
border-bottom: 3px solid #67CAD4;
}

.style-tabela-ordens {
height: calc(100% - 125px);
}

.style-tabela {
display: block;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
overflow: auto;
overflow-y: auto;
}

.menuBck {
float: left;
width: calc(100% - 20px);
}

.style-tabela > table {
overflow-y: scroll;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
width: 99.5% !important;
}

.style-tabela > table td, .style-tabela > table th {
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border: 1px solid;
white-space: nowrap;
 }

.style-tabela > table > thead th {

top: -1px;
position: sticky;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is coming from: **position: sticky;**

One option is to add an outline to your table header:

```
.style-tabela > table > thead th {
    top: 0px;
    position: sticky;
    outline: 1px solid;                         
    border:none; 
    outline-offset: -1px;
}
```